# Pushing an array reference repeatedly: the pushed references end up all equal

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I want to create a 2d array(`@combinations`) that holds all combinations of another array (`@indices`).

I'm using `push` to append a reference to another array(`@temp2`). When I print my 2d array  (using `Dumper`) it is not as I expect: the `print` statement inside the loop shows that every pushed reference is to a non-empty list, but eventually all my references point to an empty list. Why?

```
use Math::Combinatorics;
use Data::Dumper;


my (@combinations, @temp2);

my @indices = (0, 2, 4);

my $count = 1;

my $counter = @indices;

while ($counter>= $count) {

    my $c = Math::Combinatorics->new( 
    count     => $count,
    data      => \@indices,           
    );

    $count++;

    while (@temp2 =  $c->next_combination) {

        print "@temp2 \n";
        push @combinations, \@temp2;

    }
}

print Dumper(\@combinations);
```

Comment: Another improvement: `for my $count (1..@indices) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

Because you declare `@temp2` at the top level, the reference `\@temp2` will always point to the same data. Because you exit the loop as soon as `@temp2` is empty, all the references in `@combinations` will point to this same empty array.

The remedy is easy: declare the `@temp2` to be local to the `while` loop, by writing

```
while (my @temp2 =  $c->next_combination) {
```

This will create a *new* variable `@temp2`, with its own reference, each time the loop is repeated.

Comment: Or better yet - don't use `@temp2` when you actually want an array reference. Declare it as a scalar: `my $temp_ref = @{ $c->next_combination }` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, especially for Mr Hans.

Comment: @Sobrique, I think you meant `my $temp_ref = [ $c->next_combination ]`, but that makes no sense either cause the loop will never end.

Comment: @blukasz: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, consider accepting it: this will show people coming here with the same problem that the answer was useful, and get you (and me...) some reputation-points.